# Getting credis to work in a C++ solution

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, window, redis

I'm working on a C++ project where I must connect to redis database. I'm trying to get the [credis](http://code.google.com/p/credis/) code to work but when I compile it I get these sets of errors

```
1>c:\c++redis\credis.c(728): warning C4013: 'fcntl' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>c:\c++redis\credis.c(728): error C2065: 'F_GETFL' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\c++redis\credis.c(729): error C2065: 'F_SETFL' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\c++redis\credis.c(729): error C2065: 'O_NONBLOCK' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\c++redis\credis.c(734): error C2065: 'EINPROGRESS' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\c++redis\credis.c(740): warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'char *'
```

The error is in the `credis.c` file from line 728 to 746

```
/* connect with user specified timeout */
flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
if ((rc = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
DEBUG("Setting socket non-blocking failed with: %d\n", rc);
}

if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) != 0) {
if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
    goto error;

if (cr_selectwritable(fd, timeout) > 0) {
    int err;
    unsigned int len = sizeof(err);
    if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &err, &len) == -1 || err)
    goto error;
}
else /* timeout or select error */
    goto error;
}
/* else connect completed immediately */
```

Where can I find these missing typenames?

I'm using visual studio 2010 to compile this and the program must run on window.

I have tried to batch the code with [this](http://code.google.com/p/credis/issues/detail?id=41) suggested answer, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Downvoter Why? What do I need to edit to make this question more clear to you?

Comment: @jalf Fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at least one header file missing:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

that should fix some of your issues.  Generally, a good place to look for the header file names is in the help text for the function itself.  In this case the header file has the same name as the function (`fcntl`) but most are not that easy.

`EINPROGRESS`is defined in:

```
#include <errno.h>
```

for future reference, the `E` prefix usually means it is an error macro, so `errno.h` is the first place to look.

`'function' : incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'char *'` probably means you have a prototype mis-match.  Your prototype does not match the function itself.  Update the prototype.

Edit:
Although that will fix some of your issues, it appears that this is UNIX code (see comments).  `F_GETFL` and `F_SETFL`, for example, appears not to be supported on Windows.  `O_NONBLOCK` is in `unistd.h` on UNIX.

You will need to rewrite the parts of the code requiring this functionality or, better yet, get the Windows version from your supplier.

From your updated post, these are done using sockets.  Sockets are fairly portable, but there are some issues.  For non-blocking sockets use `ioctlsocket()` on Windows.

Example:

```
int iRetn = ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, 1);
```

where `s` is the socket, the third parameter is 0 for blocking, non-zero for non-blocking.

You also need to `#include <winsock.h>` and call `WSAStartup()` before using any socket routines, and call `WSACleanup()` at end.

(To be honest that's all I can think of right now, I didn't realise I would be answering issues on sockets).

Comment: Thanks, that fixes half the errors. F_GETFL, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK still give error but the others one have disappeared.

Comment: To clarify, `fcntl` and `EINPROGRESS1` "disappeared" once I include those files.

Comment: @Caesar: OK, try: `#include <sys/types.h>`, `#include <sys/stat.h>`

Comment: @Caesar: This smells of UNIX code.  You sure this is the Windows version?

Comment: I have read about about people who have got it work in windows and this is the only version I can find to download. But yeah, this does seem to be a unix code.

Comment: @Caesar:  then you have to port the code.  to be honest if you are struggling with these simple issues then you don't stand much chance of doing a port yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to find a good library for redis that works for windows and C++

Comment: Thanks @cdarke. I think your answer is prefect but I don't have the skill or the time to rewrite the code. I'm gone look into a different library.

Answer (score 2):

The library works well on linux,but not windows.
On Windows,I use https://code.google.com/p/libredic/